# Hover action on Acordeon menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm searching for a solution how to open and close the accordeon by hoovering over the parent links? I know i could add an hover-method but it always closes the accordeon when I remove the cursor. I should only close a menu when I'm hovering an a other item.

Would be great if someone could give me a hint!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 
});
```

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" >Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here the same thing in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8y60hre0/8/

Comment: *I know i could add an hover-method but it always closes the accordeon when I remove the cursor.* - Can you add that version of the code? What you have up here doesn't have the bug (so we can't debug it).

Comment: Dito @BSMP 's comment above. I'm not experiencing the issue you're describing. I created a jsfiddle, swapping out "click" with "hover" or "mouseover", and it seems to work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/Currell/m8hvcxpx/

Comment: It is looking great, thank you very much!
Just one little or big problem: the menu with the li class"active" element should stay open by default and should not close when hovering on other parent items.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }else{
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
  });

    $('#nav > li > a').hover(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });



  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
        $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
    $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

When using it I had just some problems because on a active page (li class="ative") the menu is opened by default and when I'm hovering other parent items the menu is closing up and down for about three times. I think the menu with the li class "active" should stay open all the time - also when I'm hovering on other parent items. How can I acheive that?